# Error copying range using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble copying a range when using a variable to refer to the range being copied. The error i get is:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Sub temp()
Dim Data As Range
Set Data = Range("A1:C1")
Range(Data).Copy Range("E1")
End Sub
```

There is no problem if i use

```
Range("A1:C1").Copy Range("E1")
```

I also tried

```
Range(Data).Copy Destination:=Range("E1")
```

I'm using Excel 2010. The above sample is part of a larger body of code. I've isolated the part which generates the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Data = Range("A1:C1")`

```
Data.Copy Range("E1")
```

should work ..